# Using PhoneGap with Angular2, problems loading templates

Tags: cordova, angular, traceur, systemjs

It seems like systemjs can't seem to find the template files (my .html views) because it uses absolute paths to load the files. It expects my main app component app.html to be located at `file://` but the fact is, PhoneGap places the root of the application pretty deep down the line of `file://data/data/app-name/root/...` 
The reason systemjs loads from / might be because i added a `<base href="/">` to my `index.html`. This is done to get the routing to work though.

What is the best practise here? All my components uses templateUrl and i'm seriously considering inlineing the html instead - which would be really annoying...

I'm using traceur as transpiler.

Comment: Is related to [this](https://github.com/systemjs/builder/issues/234)?

Comment: @lifeisfoo i think it is very related, but i don't see how to apply it to my problem.

Comment: did you get cordova and angular2 running? I am facing issues. It stops at loading... what basic app structure did you use to initialise the boot.ts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, i solved that problem in a two step fix:

First, in my index.html, where i import my app, before i do that, i initialize a global variable that i use later as a baseUrl:

```
if (window.cordova !== undefined) {
    baseLoadpath = 'data/data/dk.app_name/files/download/app_dir/';
} else {
    baseLoadpath = '/'
}
```

Whenever i load a template, i prepend this baseLoadPath like this:

```
@View({
    templateUrl : baseLoadpath + 'app.html' 
})
```

That takes care of the file paths. I still can't get it up and running in PhoneGap due to other erros...

Comment: Hi. Did you manange to work Phonegap with Angular 2? And do you use TypeScript or JavaScript?

Comment: @DanielDudas nope, i put that idea on hold and just sticking to adding the webpage as a "homepage app"/link